# How to label negative and postive values on each bar in a grouped barplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to label each bar in a grouped barplot in ggplot2. Each group is aggregated by date and there are 4 values (bars) for each date. I've seen and actually have code of my own that labels single negative and positive bars properly, but I cannot get a grouped barplot to work properly. The values keep ending up inside the bar.

My data:

```
    Date <- c("2016-02-19", "2016-02-20", "2016-02-21", "2016-02-22", "2016-02-23", "2016-02-24", "2016-02-25", "2016-02-26", "2016-02-27", "2016-02-28",
"2016-02-29", "2016-03-01", "2016-03-02", "2016-03-03", "2016-03-04")

Date <- as.Date(Date)

Model1 <- c(-0.6, -0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, -0.2, -1.7, 0.7, 3.6, 2.0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)

Model2 <- c(-0.5, -0.2, -0.5,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0, -0.9,  1.6,  3.6, -0.2,  2.1,  7.8,  3.5, -3.4, -8.1)

Model3 <- c( -0.7,  0.0,  0.2,  0.4,  0.8,  0.6,  0.8, -0.4, -0.6,  0.2,  0.1, -0.9, -0.5,  0.1,  0.3)

Model4 <- c(-0.4, -0.1, -0.2, -0.2, -0.7, -1.5, -1.5, -1.5,  0.1,  1.3,  1.1,  0.9,  0.2, -1.1, -1.7)

df <- data.frame(Date, Model1, Model2, Model3, Model4)

df <- melt(df, id.vars="Date", value.name="Value", variable.name = "model")
```

The code I am using to plot:

```
dfplot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Date, y = Value, fill = model)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge",stat = "identity", aes(fill= model)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red","blue", "dark green", "purple"))+
  geom_text(aes(label= Value),position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
  vjust = ifelse(df[,3]>=0, -0.5, 1) , size= 3)
```

[image: My result]

As you can see, the value labels are not on top (or on bottom) of each bar as I would like. Some are, but a good number are not.

When it comes to labeled grouped barplots with only positive values, I saw examples that using `position= position_dodge(width=0.9)` is the best way to go and I agree. I got the most productive results with it, but it's not perfect.

I think my issue lies within my vjust ifelse statement. If I leave vjust as -0.5 instead of the ifelse statement, all positive bars actually are labeled correctly, but the negative values are still within the bars, but the image actually looks cleaner than the one posted above.

any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `aes(x,y)` instead of `vjust`:

```
geom_text(aes(label= Value, 
              x=Date, 
              y=Value+ifelse(Value>=0,0.01, -0.5)),
          position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
          vjust = -0.5 , size= 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.